# “I saw him be upset/to be upset/ being upset”

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, infinitives

I'll use *seeing* and *upset* to create an example that might help me:

Out of these, which is correct, or which are best? Do some work in some circumstances and not others?

- I saw *him upset.*
- I saw *him to be upset.*
- I saw *him being upset.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I saw him upset." and "I saw him being upset." are grammatically correct.

Both are rather awkward ("I saw him being upset" is the more awkward of the two), however, people would probably just say "He was upset when I saw him."